# Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded for some url-key

Tags: magento2

my website has been running for while and the url key for some category have been using for long. but suddenly some category pages (most others are still valid) referenced by url-key.html not working. the backend report show

[image]
Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

i tried to delete the url-key and give a new one, but not successful. there is error also.

[image]
do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

**Issue 1**. "Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded", there are 2 cases related to this error message:

- **Case 1** (your case), only some pages have this error, so your data caused this error. To resolve that, take the following step to override `vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php`:

Step 1: Create registration.php:

File path: `app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create module.xml:

File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Framework"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the `di.xml`:

File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" type="Vendor\Module\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
</config>
```

Step 4: Create Json.php:

File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Serialize\Serializer;

class Json extends \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
{
    public function serialize($data) {
        $result = json_encode($this->utf8ize($data));
        if (false === $result) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function unserialize($string)
    {
        if ($string === null) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Invalid parameter: string must be a string type, null given.')
            );
        }

        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            if (false !== @unserialize($string)) {
                return unserialize($string);
            }
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function utf8ize($mixed) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
        elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        return $mixed;
    }
}
```

Step 6: Run the `setup:upgrade` command to make your new module active, and then compile code, deploy static content:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Done.

- **Case 2**: If your error trace said the error was related to Magento Recaptcha module, you faced the issue with MSP_ReCaptcha module (magento core module), check the github issue for more details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30486

> This is due to the MSP_ReCaptcha module storing the public key in
> plain text (type="text"), but the Magento recaptcha module stores it
> encrypted (type="obscure"). The migration however just copies the
> plain text value over, so when it is "decrypted", the resulting value
> is invalid.
>
> To fix this get the msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/general/public_key
> value from the core_config_data (or your Google ReCaptcha admin page)
> and run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento config:set recaptcha_frontend/type_invisible/public_key YOURPUBLICKEY
php bin/magento config:set recaptcha_backend/type_invisible/public_key YOURPUBLICKEY
```

> The command correctly encrypts the value when adding it
> to the database.

**Issue 2**. URL rewrite issue: try to use **Elgentos Regenerate Catalog URLs** module to regenerate URL rewrites: https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls

In case you still have issues, feel free to let me know.

Comment: For case 1, I follow your code to build the module, both setup:upgrade and di:compile finished without issue. but when setup:static-content:deploy, it complains "Class Secuware\Serializer\Serialize\Serializer\Json does not exist", I called my module Secuware_Serializer. my file is in app/code/Secuware/Serializer/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php. am I wrong?

Comment: Please change the file paths for `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` and `Vendor/Module/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php ` to follow the latest update in my answer.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood, but i see the paths have been the same as yours. app\code\Secuware\Serializer\Serialize\Serializer\Json.php and app\code\Secuware\Serializer\etc\di.xml, i replace Vendor with Secuware and Module with Serializer. am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is correct, please double-check file paths and namespace in Json class, di.xml file as my answer. I've tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

create:

Vendor\Framework\registration.php

```
    <?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Framework',
    __DIR__
);
```

Vendor\Framework\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Framework">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Framework" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Vendor\Framework\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Json" type="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" type="Vendor\Framework\Rewrite\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
</config>
```

Vendor\Framework\Rewrite\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Framework\Rewrite\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer;

class Json extends \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
{
    public function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
        elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        return $mixed;
    }


    public function serialize($data){
        $result = json_encode( $this->utf8ize( $data ) );
        if (false === $result) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }
        return $result;
    }

    
    public function unserialize($string)
    {
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE)
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to unserialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```